# LSF/Slurm equivalent command

Tags: slurm, lsf

There are few `bjobs` commande that I can't reproduce with slurm.
I'm looking for the equivalence of :

- `alloc_slot`
- `nalloc_slot`
- `slot`
- memory usage per node

Especially, I'm wondering whether it's possible to the retrieve the **requested and used** number of slot per node.
Like, it happens that user requests a full node, so lets say 122 cores, but actually use only 4 cores.

Have someone already faced this situation ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Especially, I'm wondering whether it's possible to the retrieve the requested and used number of slot per node.

You can have a look at `scontrol show nodes`. You will get information such as `CPUAlloc=0`, the number of allocated slots on the node and `CPULoad=0.01` the actual load of the node, which should match the number `CPUAlloc`.

> Like, it happens that user requests a full node, so lets say 122 cores, but actually use only 4 cores.

In such a situation you would see `CPUAlloc=122` and `CPULoad=4.00`.

> memory usage per node

The same command will output `AllocMem=0` which is the sum of memory requests for the node and `FreeMem=xxx` which is what is reported by the `free` command and is the amount of memory not used by any program. You will need to compare those numbers with the total available memory on the node. In case of perfect memory usage by the jobs and no memory usage by the OS, `AllocMem` + `FreeMem` should be equal to `RealMemory`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.
Do you know whether there is a way to collect those information in the accounting data base ? A plugin maybe ? Or do I have to write one ?

Comment: They should be in the database if accounting is enabled. See the list of variables that are stored here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html#OPT_helpformat

Comment: yes, but not by node for a given jobid